# Prove Zero Mean Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean

I have a stochastic process for which I can compute a final outcome that is real valued. I know that the process has a relatively high variance and is costly to obtain more data points. (which I know are uncorrelated)

Is there a method to rank my hypothesis of the mean being zero based on a few hundred results?

I know from Central Limit Theorem that the sample mean would behave as a normal variable with its mean equal to the original process mean and variance equal to the original variance divided by the number of sample points. But for the number of data points I have this would represent a very loose bound for my application.

Also, note that I don't have any a priori distribution, as the process is very complex to handle.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean "rank" your hypothesis? What are you trying to do / show? What hypothesis? How much data do you have? Do you have any? How variable is this process, roughly?

Comment: @user2974951 : I needed some technical argument to tell that the hypothesis was (at least likely) correct. The hypothesis is *"this process has zero mean"*. I have 1560 data points. The mean I compute from it at different time steps but averaged with the 1560 simulations is around +/-  0.005 while the deviation is around 0.14.  Really seems to fit the CLT. But this mean of 0.005 is still relevant against the exact zero hypothesis.

Comment: So you are testing whether the mean from your simulations is equal to 0, and in your case it was equal to 0.005, but the standard error was too high and you were not able to reject this hypothesis? And now you want to say something about the mean being "close enough" to 0?

Comment: I've computed the mean form simulations to be in the interval +/- 0.005.  The mean is done over each simulation at same time step. Theoretically, the process would have zero mean. I can say due to CLT that the mean is around +/- 0.005 +/- 0.0106 at 3 sigma level, so this interval does contain 0, but is too wide. And also, if the mean actually were 0.0001 this would already reject the hypothesis I'm trying to prove.

Comment: You are mixing things up and it's not clear anymore what's going on. What are these simulations you refer to? What did you do in said simulations and what did they show (results)? Do you have any actual data? Why do you keep citing the CTL? Why does your mean have both signs?